# How to configure IIS Express in order to allow a non-administrator to use SSL ports outside the range of 44300 to 44399?

Tags: ssl, iis, iis-express, http.sys

According to the [IIS Express documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/using-iis-express/running-iis-express-without-administrative-privileges#using-ssl) administrative privileges are needed to run SSL using a port outside the range of 44300 to 44399.

For non-administrative users IIS Express

- configures HTTP.SYS to reserve ports 44300 through 44399 for SSL
- associates incoming SSL localhost requests in that range with a pre-installed self-signed SSL certificate

Is there a way to enable non-administrative users to run SSL on IIS-Express using a port outside the range of 44300 to 44399?

E.g. can I use `netsh http add urlacl` to open up SSL ports outside the range of 44300 to 44399 for `user=EVERYONE` ?
E.g. can I use `netsh http add sslcert` to add the self-signed certicate to ports outside the range of 44300 to 44399 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIS Express installer creates several IP based bindings in Windows HTTP API, and that's why 44300-44399 has been enabled by default.

You can feel free to create more such bindings (via `netsh http add sslcert` command), but creation of them requires administrator permissions.

[Reference](https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/https-binding.html#ip-based-bindings)

`netsh http add urlacl` is not needed, as it serves other purposes.